# How can i get all the mentioned users from a channel discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm new to discord js and I'm wondering how I can get all the mentioned users of a channel

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You should attempt at writing the code yourself before coming here with actual code and errors you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fetch the messages, like this: `let messages = await message.channel.fetchMessages();`. Then you can scan every message for user mentions. Example:

```js
let msgs = [];
messages.map(m => {
if (m.mentions.users.size()) msgs.push(message.mentions.users.first().id);
});
```

Now you have an array (`msgs`) containing every mentioned user id in the specified channel.

Comment: I did it this way, but it didn't work, sorry if it's a silly mistake, I'm a beginner!


 ``` 
client.on('message', async msg => {
  if (msg.author.id == client.user.id && msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith(`comecar`)) {
    console.log(`Iniciando os trabalhos!`);
 message.channel.fetchMessages().then(messages => {
  if (m.mentions.users.size()) membros.push(message.mentions.users.first().id);
 })
  }
});
```

Comment: You're trying to call `message` but you need to call `msg`. Sorry for the confusion!
The right code should look like this: 
`client.on('message', async msg => {
  if (msg.author.id == client.user.id && msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith('comecar')) {
  console.log('Iniciando os trabalhos!');
  let msgs = [];
  msg.channel.fetchMessages().then(m => {
    if (m.mentions.users.size()) msgs.push(message.mentions.users.first().id);
    })
  }
});`